# add viewbag list of string to checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have a variable listSiteGroup that contains list of strings, and I put it in ViewBag

```
ViewBag.listSiteGroup = listSiteGroup;
```

how do I show each of my string to checkboxes?

I want to show it to the user like this

[ ]sitegroup 1

[ ]sitegroup 2

[ ]sitegroup 3

[ ]sitegroup 4


currently, I looped using for to each viewbag and put it in checkboxfor like the code below

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.listSiteGroup.Count(); i++ )
{
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(ViewBag.listSiteGroup[i].IsEnabled, new {nama=ViewBag.listSiteGroup[i].nama })
}
```

I'm new to asp.net mvc, I just assume this is how I access each of the viewbag

Comment: `CheckBoxFor()` is for binding to a `bool` property, not a `string`

Comment: I know, I'm going to store the bool data into the database. I just need to show the string to the user as choices. I don't know if you understand what I mean

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.yourBoolProperty, Model.stringProperty)`

Comment: `CheckBoxFor` is not intended to use with `ViewBag`, use strongly-typed viewmodel instead (assumed `IsEnabled` is boolean property). If you want to use string property as label inside loop, just do `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.listSiteGroup[i].IsEnabled, Model.listSiteGroup[i].EnabledTextProperty)`.